# How to use lapply with a function that requires a vector as an argument

Tags: r, list, functional-programming

I'm trying to find where in a list of vectors I have a 3 or a 1, but I have no idea how to do it with lapply if the function I'm using requires an vector as an argument. Ex.:

```r
k <- list(c(2, 0, 2, 1), c(3, 0, 2, 0), c(0, 1, 2, 0))
lapply(k, match(c(1, 3), k)) # The problem is here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` takes a `list` as its first argument and a function as its second. Optional arguments for the function can be added as additional arguments to `lapply`.

By using `match(c(1,3), k)`, you are calling `match` on `c(1, 3)` and your list `k`. What you want to do is to pass a function to `lapply` that will take a vector `x` as argument and return `match(c(1, 3), x)`. `lapply` will then execute this function on each element of your list `k`.

This is how you should use `lapply`:

```
k <- list(c(2,0,2,1),c(3,0,2,0),c(0,1,2,0))
lapply(k, function(x) match(c(1,3), x))
# [[1]]
# [1]  4 NA
#
# [[2]]
# [1] NA  1
#
# [[3]]
# [1]  2 NA
```

Comment: Hopefully OP is aware that match only returns the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @Samuel Diebolt uses an anonymous function call in `lapply`. To use it without the anonymous call the syntax would be

```
lapply(k, match, x = c(1, 3))

#[[1]]
#[1]  4 NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA  1

#[[3]]
#[1]  2 NA
```